# 20 mongodbs servers centralized to only 1

Tags: mongodb, server, cluster-computing, business-intelligence

I would like to know how I can make 20 instances of mongodb, each with a database with the name that is a unique number, synchronize these databases and their data to a central database.

Eg:

```
Server 1 - Database 1
Server 2 - Database 2
...
Server 20 - Database 20
Central Server - Database 1, 2, 3, ..., 20
```

Can anybody provide me with some articles? Github repo?
I'm tring to use the:
https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector
But I'm having a lot of problems with the authentication part... Each server need to have their own user so each server will only see their data.
Already tried to create a custom role in my authSource/database with the following privileges: createCollection, find, insert, update, listCollections and listDatabases. But it didn't work either.

I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) from each of the discrete databases and setup a listener on each of those streams that can write all changes to central database. you need MongoDB 3.6 or greater to use Change Streams.